# Entity Framework Core - How can I extract details about the underlying SQL syntax?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm writing a library that requires the use of a recursive (CTE) query to efficiently fetch some data. Obviously this is not possible to do using Entity Framework and LINQ. As a result, I have used the `FromSql` command to run the raw query against the database. However, my query was designed and works against MySQL/MariaDB. When I run it against postgres, there are some minor syntax differences that cause it to break.

Ideally, I would like to avoid hardcoding (copy and pasting) the same query 3 times to work with postgres, mysql and potentially MS SQL. Given a `DbContext` is there any way I can drill down and get specific SQL syntax information from the underlying provider? For example MySQL uses a backtick as a quoted identifier, and Postgres uses double quotes, MS SQL is wrapped in `[` and `]`. Is there any way I can fetch this type of information from the underlying provider to hopefully make my `FromSQL` raw query as robust as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All which comes to my mind in EF Core 2.x is the [ISqlGenerationHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.isqlgenerationhelper?view=efcore-2.1) interface (service). It's quite limited, but provides  [DelimitIdentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.isqlgenerationhelper.delimitidentifier?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Storage_ISqlGenerationHelper_DelimitIdentifier_System_String_) method which does what you are asking for. And is used by the [DefaultQuerySqlGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.sql.defaultquerysqlgenerator?view=efcore-2.1) shared by all provider SQL generators, so I guess it should be enough.

Since this is internal service, you'd need

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
```

in order to get access to `GetService` extension method, and

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
```

for `ISqlGenerationHelper` interface.

The usage is like this:

```
var sqlGeneratorHelper = dbContext.GetService<ISqlGenerationHelper>();
var tableName = sqlGeneratorHelper.DelimitIdentifier("MyTable");
// SqlServer: [MyTable]
```